# How to show the outputs folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to show the outputs folder in Android Studio?
The following is the folder structure in Windows Explorer:

[image]

The following is the corresponding part in Android Studio:
[image]

I am particularly interested in the mapping folder under outputs because I use it frequently. I want to open files in that folder within Android Studio.

Comment: Have you tried to choose a different tree structure? By clicking "Android" above the folders, you can choose "Projects" or other structures. Perhaps you'll can retrieve your output folder

Comment: Yes, I have tried every one of them.